# dynamically calculate number of processes to be spawned

Tags: python, process, fork, multiprocessing, spawn

I have a list of about 15 years in the year_queue, I need to spawn one process for each year. But depending on which server I am running the code, the number of processors vary. How do I dynamically vary the variable num_processes depending on the number of processers in the server?

If I set num_processes > number of processers, would it automatically spawn accordingly? When I test this - it creates 15 processes & splits the CPU power between them. I am looking for a way to first create 'n' number of processes, where n = number of processers in the server, and then as each of those processes finish, the next is spawned.

```
for i in range(num_processes):
    worker = ForEachPerson(year_queue, result_queue, i, dict_of_files)
    print "worker spawned for " + str(i)
    worker.start()

results = []
while len(results) < len(years):
    result = result_queue.get()
    results.append(result)
```

Anyone had the same issue?

---

```
while year_queue.empty() != True:
    for i in range(num_processes):
      worker = ForEachPerson(year_queue, result_queue, i, dict_of_files)
      print "worker spawned for " + str(i)
      worker.start()

    # collect results off the queue
    print "results being collected"
    results = []
    while len(results) < len(num_processes):
      result = result_queue.get()
      results.append(result)
```

Comment: Use multiprocessing.cpu_count to dynamically determine how many processes to spawn. Put everything into a single multiprocessing.Queue, and then spawn as many processes as you have cpus, and then get() from the queue in each processes until you encounter an Empty exception.

Comment: @oxtopus: using your solution, I was able to spawn as many processes as I had cpu's. So for the 15 workers that I need to spawn, and 4 cpu's that I have, I spawn 4 processes first, then my solution is having to wait for all the result_queue.get()s to complete, before it goes to the next iteration of four new processes being spawned.

So essentially, for each iteration, all four processes had to finish, before the next set could start. Any workaround for this?

Comment: code for above comment added to initial question for formatting

Answer (score 4):

Use a [multiprocessing Pool](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool). The class does all the tedious work of selecting the right number of processes and running them for you. It also doesn't spawn a new process for each task, but reuses processes once they're done.

```
def process_year(year):
    ...
    return result

pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
results = pool.map(process_year, year_queue)
```

Comment: I am trying to understand the Pool class, to try it this way. Does just using pool.map, start a new process & also get the results?

Comment: Yes. It makes sure the processes are running, has them run the tasks, and returns the results as a list.

Answer (score 0):

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, cpu_count
from Queue import Empty

class ForEachPerson(Process):
    def __init__(self, year_queue, result_queue, i, dict_of_files):
        self.year_queue=year_queue
        self.result_queue=result_queue
        self.i=i
        self.dict_of_files=dict_of_files
        super(ForEachPerson, self).__init__()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            try:
                year=self.year_queue.get()

                ''' Do something '''

                self.result_queue.put(year)
            except Empty:
                self.result_queue.close()
                return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    year_queue=Queue()
    result_queue=Queue()
    dict_of_files={}

    start_year=1996
    num_years=15

    for year in range(start_year, start_year + num_years):
        year_queue.put(year)

    workers=[]
    for i in range(cpu_count()):
        worker = ForEachPerson(year_queue, result_queue, i, dict_of_files)
        print 'worker spawned for', str(i)
        worker.start()
        workers.append(worker)

    results=[]
    while len(results) < num_years:
        try:
            year=result_queue.get()
            results.append(year)
            print 'Result:', year
        except Empty:
            pass

    for worker in workers:
        worker.terminate()
```

Comment: the above changes you mentioned did give me the right results, but threw this error before it exited. 

*** SIGTERM received by PID 28042 (TID 28042) from PID 27919; stack trace: ***
PC: @     0x7fbe30512195  (unknown)  malloc_consolidate
    @     0x7fbe2e8ff396       1216  FailureSignalHandler()
    @     0x7fbe30eba9e0  (unknown)  __restore_rt